# How to create chat room in ejabberd through rest api?

Tags: oauth, ejabberd, multiuserchat, ejabberd-api

I know that I can create chat room in ejabberd using command

`ejabberdctl create_room room_name muc_service xmpp_domain`

and I can send invites to users using command

`ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation room_name password reason jid1[:jid2]`

Can someone tell me how to do the same using ejabberd rest api ?

I'm using oauth for authentication.

I've done following configuration in ejabberd.yml file

`port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/log": mod_log_http
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
      "/api": mod_http_api
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    register: true
    captcha: true
commands_admin_access: configure
commands:
  - add_commands: 
    - user
    - status
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all`

and also enabled mod_muc_admin in ejabberd.yml file using

`modules: 
  mod_muc_admin: {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mod_restful module for accessing ejabberd through api. You need to configure below lines in ejabberd.yml if you want to access that module.

```
mod_restful:
api:
  - path: ["admin"]
    module: mod_restful_admin
    params:
      key: "secret"
      allowed_commands: [register, unregister,status, add_rosteritem, create_room, send_direct_invitation, set_room_affiliation]
  - path: ["register"]
    module: mod_restful_register
    params:
      key: "secret"
```

They commands that are declared in allowed_commands, only those commands are accessible through api. So in future if you want to access any other commands you need to add here.

once you finished adding ,restart ejabberd and you can access api either with postman or with curl

```
/* 
            Data that need to be sent for creating group.

            Url : example.com:8088/api/admin/
            Content-Type: application/json

            {"key": "secret","command": "create_room","args": ["group1","conference.example.com","example.com"]}


*/
```

Similar like this try for send_direct_invitation too...

Comment: where should I write these settings, i.e., under modules or somewhere else in ejabberd.yml file. Further, what does this "key" : "secret" mean, should I send it as it is, actually I'm using oauth, so how can I use it here.

Comment: you need to add this in ejabberd.yml under modules section and key is used for authentication purpose such that to know whether the right person is accessing this port . You can change the value of key by changing the value in ejabberd.yml.

Comment: @ManiKandan which ejabberd version have you used with the above config ?

Comment: ejabberd version is 16.04.43

Answer (score 0):

To do the api request to create a room,

Do a curl post,

`curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "name": "aaaaa",
    "service": "bbbbb",
    "host": "ccccc"
}' "http://localhost:5280/api/create_room"`

Or if you want to add multiple room in a single stoke, add all the room names in a file, say the file name is `aaaaa`

do a curl as this,

`curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "file": "aaaaa"
}' "http://localhost:5280/api/create_rooms_file"`

Comment: Using 5280 port is okay, but the same port can be accessed in webpanel too so configuring mod_resful which uses port 8088 for api's is recommendable .